# Custom Ribbon tab missing in Excel

Tags: excel, ribbonx

I tried searching for this question but couldn't really find a similar problem.

I have an excel file in which I created a custom ribbon tab and made copies of this file.

[Image of the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuWDq.png)

In some of those copies, the tab has gone missing. I was earlier using Excel 2016 and recently migrated to Microsoft 365 and downloaded the latest version of Office. I am not sure if this is causing the problem since some files do still have the custom ribbon.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any UI errors when the tab is missed?

By default, if an add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors you need:

1. Start the application.
2. Click the `File` tab.
3. Click `Options`.
4. In the categories pane, click `Advanced`.
5. In the details pane, select `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors`, and then click OK.

If you deal with documents with embedded customizations, make sure the protected mode is off when the document is opened. See [What is Protected View?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene, 

I don't get any errors even the "Show Add-in user interface errors" is checked.  Just to clarify, my custom tab is not an add-in but was made using Andy Pope's ribbon designer.

I have a feeling that when I access my file online through online excel from my office account, it makes the custom tab disappear.

Comment: A custom tab can be displayed in the desktop edition of MS Office.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier. What I meant was that once I access the file in the online version of Excel, the tab completely disappears in the desktop version of Excel as well. This is what my guess is at the moment as I am not exactly sure what is causing the custom tab to disappear from the desktop version of excel. May be it is one drive but I am not sure.

Comment: Most probably you save the excel file as macro-enabled which doesn't make sense for the online edition of Office. After opening it back in the desktop edition it is opened as not macro-enabled document, correct?